# Google API always prompting?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am having trouble with application awlays prompting user to grant access to app after token expire (1 hour). I was looking older issues, but nothing helped me. If anyone has time to review my code and find mistake, I would be grateful.

```
  function getClient()
    {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  //disable SSL
  $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array( 'curl' => array( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, ), ));
  $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
  $sample_passthrough_value = 'someregularstring22';
  $client->setApplicationName('GDrive_Trello');
  $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
  $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
  $client->setState($sample_passthrough_value);
  $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true); 
  
  
  $tokenPath = 'token.json';
  if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
      $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
      $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
  }

  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
          $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
      } else {
          $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
          header("Location: " . $authUrl);
          if(isset($_GET['code'])){
              $authCode = $_GET['code'];    
              header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            } else{
                $authCode= null;
            }
            
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

          if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
              throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
          }
      }
      if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
          mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
      }
      file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  } 
  return $client;
}
```

Comment: Unless you store the refresh token some place its going to.  whats in the file stored in token.json your not loading the refresh token.

Comment: Token.json contains refresh token if that's what you are pointing? If it's not, I'm not sure what excatly to do. Can you give me example? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is start reading the refresh token from the token.json file.  I dont have php installed right now so i cant test this.  Just make sure that you load it then use `setRefreshToken` to set it as part of the client object.  To test it just print out the $client object to be sure that its set.

```
$tokenPath = 'token.json';
  if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
      $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
      $refresToken= // do something hear to load that refresh token;
      $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
      $client->RefreshToken($refresToken);
  }
```

Then when you check for `isAccessTokenExpired` the library should automaticly be loading you a new access token.

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
```

Comment: Nice logic, unfortunately there is no such method setRefreshToken, but I'll try to stick to this logic. Thanks again!

Comment: Remove the set its just refreshToken  $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']) is what I use when its a web based app